# Using different Linux I/O schedulers for different block devices

Tags: linux, io, linux-kernel, filesystems, disk

Is it possible to configure Linux to use different I/O schedulers for different block devices?

For example:
I have 2 block devices

- dev0:Disk-drive
- dev1:FlashDrive

And I want Linux to continue using the CFQ scheduler for `dev0`, but use Noop scheduler for `dev1`.

If possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `echo <scheduler_name> > /sys/block/<device>/queue/scheduler`